# getting data from combobox to a datagridview

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms application. I have two combo boxes , comboA and comboB.I have a datagrid view with two columns. Now I have to populate the datagrid view, with selected item from comboA into first column of datagridview    and     selected item of comboB into the second column. Please suggest me.

To be clear, When I select an item from comboA, it should be displayed in first column of datagridview.   And similary when i select an item from comboB , it should be displayed in the second column of the datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to populate the first row in your datagridview:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = comboBox1.Text;
}

private void comboBox2_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = comboBox2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. But I am getting an error saying : Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Have you added a row to the datagridview? (you need to add the columns first..)

Comment: I did it.
Here is the code.
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr2 = null;
            dt2.Columns.Add("key");
            dt2.Columns.Add("value");
            dr2 = dt2.NewRow();
            dr2["key"] = comboA.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dr2["value"] = comboB.SelectedItem.ToString();
            dt2.Rows.Add(dr2);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;

Answer (score -1):

I did it. Here is the code.

```
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable(); 
DataRow dr2 = null; 
dt2.Columns.Add("key"); 
dt2.Columns.Add("value");
 dr2 = dt2.NewRow(); 
dr2["key"] = comboA.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
dr2["value"] = comboB.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
dt2.Rows.Add(dr2); 
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2
```