# getting data from combobox to a data grid view c#

Tags: c#

I am using windows forms application. I have two combo boxes , comboA and comboB.I have a datagrid view with two columns. Now I have to populate the datagrid view, with selected item from comboA into first column of datagridview and selected item of comboB into the second column. Please suggest me

To be clear, When I select an item from comboA, it should be displayed in first column of datagridview. And similary when i select an item from comboB , it should be displayed in the second column of the datagridview.

Comment: And if you Click comboA again will that create a new row in the datagridview, so the more you select the more rows it will create?

If you click comboB will that create a new row or will it appear in the same row as comboA?

Comment: If you click comboB  will it appear in the same row as comboA

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864850/getting-data-from-combobox-to-a-datagridview?rq=1

Comment: i know but there is no answer